# Text moviepy and gizeh

Tags: python, moviepy

I wrote a little python program with moviepy and gizeh (thank Zulko).
It shows on screen and moves a text string "my_text" and it works fine.

```
<!-- language: python -->
# Import everything needed to edit video clips
from moviepy.editor import *
import random
import gizeh

# RESOLUTION
W = 1280
H = 720
duration = 5

def make_frame(t):
    surface = gizeh.Surface(W,H)
    text = gizeh.text("my_text", fontsize = 80, fontfamily="Impact", 
           fill=(1,1,1), xy=(W/2, (min(340,-340+1000*t) )))
    text.draw(surface)

    return surface.get_npimage()

clip2 = VideoClip(make_frame, duration=duration)

clip2.write_videofile("my_video.avi",fps=12, codec='libx264')
```

I have a poor programming skill. 
I would like to use a list of text strings ["my_text1", "my_text2", "my_text3"...]  instead than just one string "my_text". 
Furthermore these list elements should appear on the screen in succession and not at the same time. 
Can someone put me towards the right direction to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with `moviepy`, but I believe that the `t` argument provided to `make_frame` indicates how many seconds have passed. If we have a list of `text_strings` that we'd like to spread evenly through the movie (which is 5 seconds long), we'd want to divide the list up into those seconds:

```
def make_frame(t):
    surface = gizeh.Surface(W,H)
    current_text = text_strings[int((t*len(text_string))//5)]
    text = gizeh.text(current_text, fontsize = 80, fontfamily="Impact", 
           fill=(1,1,1), xy=(W/2, (min(340,-340+1000*t) )))
    text.draw(surface)
```

If you want each of them to start from the top, I'd recommend having `duration` be an (integer) variable outside of the function scope. To go through the movement `len(text_string)` times, we'd want to have it move some `max_distance` each of those times. This should do that:

```
def make_frame(t):
    surface = gizeh.Surface(W,H)
    current_text = text_strings[int((t*len(text_string))//duration)]
    text = gizeh.text(current_text, fontsize = 80, fontfamily="Impact", 
           fill=(1,1,1), 
           xy=(W/2, min(340,-340+max_distance*((t*len(text_string)/duration)%1)))
    text.draw(surface)
```

The way the rather ugly `max_distance*((t*len(text_string)/duration)%1)` works is this: `max_distance` is obviously the maximum value, so let's move inside the parentheses. `(t*len(text_string)/duration)` will move linearly from 0 to `len(text_string)` over the course of the video. The reason for this is clear when you look at `t/duration` by itself: the value of that is the fraction of how far through the video we have gone (e.g. Halfway through, `t/duration = 0.5`). The one interesting part is the use of `%1`. A primer on the modulus operator can be found elsewhere, but essentially what this will do is "restart" the proportion from 0 to 1 each time we get to a new value. This is best seen in an example:

```
t = 0
duration = 10
num_strings = 5
while t < 10:
    print(round((t*num_strings/duration)%1, 3))
    t += .1
```

Note the round is there simply so you won't see any floating point errors. Hopefully now it's clearer.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that, I wasn't aware that it used numpy floats instead of regular floats. Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Your code helped me a lot and it is interesting. 
But:  `xy=(W/2, (min(340,-340+1000*t)))` this is a transition that move the text towards the bottom of the screen. I want that this transition would operate on every text string starting from time t=0. 
I think I have to approach this in a total different way but I have no idea how

Comment: So you want each string to move from top to bottom during the 5 seconds?

Comment: Exactly! And the 5 seconds time is just a random number. 
As the number of text strings increases, probably it would make more sense to increase that number.

Comment: See my edit. Hopefully you understand what I'm doing.

Comment: It works but i'm not sure how :) Thank you, i will try harder to figure out